# Can't persist Devise user with Rails 4 Omniauth & Tumblr

Tags: oauth, devise, omniauth, tumblr, ruby-on-rails-4

Seems like I'm not the only person who has had this issue with other OAuth providers & Devise. I'm trying to authenticate a user with their Tumblr account, store their nickname as the user's username, and store their oauth token & secret so my app can automatically post to Tumblr when they take certain actions.

I've followed [various](http://www.supriyasurve.com/2012/06/rails-3-devise-omniauth-facebook.html), [articles](http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2013/03/rails-3-devise-omniauth-and-google/), [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391039/user-does-not-store-in-database-after-successful-login-from-devise-thru-omniauth?rq=1), [omniauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904401/rails-3-devise-google-auth-user-not-persisted), and devise (my code is based of the Railscast #235 episode), but I can't quite get the user's data stored in the database. The first user who tries to authenticate "works" fine (it creates a username, but nothing else), but any further users who try to login/authenticate, always get assigned that first user's credentials (and no entry in the database).

I'm using Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0-p195. Do I need to do something with Strong Parameters?

Something is going on behind the scenes with no error messages, and I just don't know how to figure out where to look. Here's my code:

```
# user.rb
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    if user = User.find_by_username(auth.info.name)
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user
    else
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.username = auth.info.nickname
        user.oauth_token = auth.info.credentials.token
        user.oauth_token_secret = auth.info.credentials.secret
      end
    end
  end
```

My controller (basically identical to every other tutuorial I've read)

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def tumblr
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in Through Tumblr!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      # flash.notice = "You are almost Done! Please provide a password to finish setting up your account"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone has ANY insight into what I may be doing wrong, or even how to figure out how to figure out (I don't mind looking, just out of ideas), I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer was fairly simple, but absolutely nothing that I suspected. When I put the ! on my create method, I got an error about my Devise-created index in my User model named: `index_users_on_email`.

So I created this migration to remove it:

```
class RemoveIndexUsersOnEmailFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_index(:users, :name => 'index_users_on_email')
  end

  def self.down
    add_index(:users, :name => 'index_users_on_email')
  end
end
```

Voila! Hope that helped someone.